# Custom data flavour for DnD rows in JTable

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

How can I register a custom data flavour, such that when I call

```
TransferHandler.TransferSupport.isDataFlavorSupported()
```

it returns true?

The flavour is initialised like so

```
private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor = new ActivationDataFlavor(DataManagerTreeNode.class, DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, "DataManagerTreeNode flavour");
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I saw only once times correct code for JTable and DnD, [offical code by Oracle](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JTabledraganddrop.htm) (former Sun)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FillViewportHeightDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    private int count = 0;
    private JTable table;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem fillBox;
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    private static String getNextString(int count) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            buf.append(String.valueOf(count));
            buf.append(",");
        }
        buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length() - 1); // remove last newline
        return buf.toString();
    }

    private static DefaultTableModel getDefaultTableModel() {
        String[] cols = {"Foo", "Toto", "Kala", "Pippo", "Boing"};
        return new DefaultTableModel(null, cols);
    }

    public FillViewportHeightDemo() {
        super("Empty Table DnD Demo");
        tableModel = getDefaultTableModel();
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);
        table.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
                if (!support.isDrop()) {  // for the demo, we'll only support drops (not clipboard paste)
                    return false;
                }
                if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {  // we only import Strings
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) { // if we can't handle the import, say so               
                if (!canImport(support)) {
                    return false;
                }
                JTable.DropLocation dl = (JTable.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();// fetch the drop location
                int row = dl.getRow();
                String data; // fetch the data and bail if this fails
                try {
                    data = (String) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                    return false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return false;
                }
                String[] rowData = data.split(",");
                tableModel.insertRow(row, rowData);
                Rectangle rect = table.getCellRect(row, 0, false);
                if (rect != null) {
                    table.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
                }
                model.removeAllElements(); // demo stuff - remove for blog
                model.insertElementAt(getNextString(count++), 0); // end demo stuff
                return true;
            }
        });
        JList dragFrom = new JList(model);
        dragFrom.setFocusable(false);
        dragFrom.setPrototypeCellValue(getNextString(100));
        model.insertElementAt(getNextString(count++), 0);
        dragFrom.setDragEnabled(true);
        dragFrom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        dragFrom.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me) && me.getClickCount() % 2 == 0) {
                    String text = (String) model.getElementAt(0);
                    String[] rowData = text.split(",");
                    tableModel.insertRow(table.getRowCount(), rowData);
                    model.removeAllElements();
                    model.insertElementAt(getNextString(count++), 0);
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JPanel wrap = new JPanel();
        wrap.add(new JLabel("Drag from here:"));
        wrap.add(dragFrom);
        p.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(4));
        p.add(Box.createGlue());
        p.add(wrap);
        p.add(Box.createGlue());
        p.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(4));
        getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        fillBox = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Fill Viewport Height");
        fillBox.addActionListener(this);
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu options = new JMenu("Options");
        mb.add(options);
        setJMenuBar(mb);
        JMenuItem clear = new JMenuItem("Reset");
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        options.add(clear);
        options.add(fillBox);
        getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260, 180));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == fillBox) {
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(fillBox.isSelected());
        } else {
            tableModel.setRowCount(0);
            count = 0;
            model.removeAllElements();
            model.insertElementAt(getNextString(count++), 0);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {//Create and set up the window.        
        FillViewportHeightDemo test = new FillViewportHeightDemo();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.pack(); //Display the window.
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {//Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```